Why does "Get Items from Pocket" shortcut action fail with "Bad Request"?
Since upgrading to iOS 18, my existing shortcut that retrieves items from Pocket fails with "Bad Request", and any new shortcut I build with the "Get Items from Pocket" action fails similarly. Is there a way to see more information about what the exactly failure is here? Are the Pocket actions in Shortcuts deprecated or unsupported?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The "Bad Request" error typically means that there's something wrong with the request being sent to Pocket's servers—this could be due to changes in how Shortcuts communicates with external services, or potentially even an update in Pocket's API.
To troubleshoot, first ensure that your Pocket account is still properly linked to the Shortcuts app. You can do this by opening the Pocket app and checking whether you're signed in, then going to Shortcuts and verifying that your Pocket account is authorized within the shortcut. Sometimes, re-authenticating the account or re-adding the Pocket action to your shortcut can resolve issues like this.
As for seeing more detailed information about the error, iOS doesn't provide built-in logs for individual shortcut failures. However, you can try isolating the problem by breaking the shortcut into smaller steps to see where exactly it fails. Another potential route would be to check Pocket's developer resources to see if there are any known issues with their API or if support for Shortcuts actions has been deprecated. If the issue persists, you may want to reach out to Pocket’s support team to confirm whether the integration is still supported on iOS 18.
